# How can I make angular enter my *ngFor loop?

Tags: angular

In the following segment of code, I display testRecords to the screen and there are test records. But the ngFor loop is not entered even though there are test records.

```
{{testRecords}}
<div class="row mb-2" *ngFor="let testRecord of testRecords">
    {{testRecord}}
    <div class="col-12">
        <h5 class="fw-semibold mb-2">{{testRecord.topic}}: {{testRecord.subtopic}}</h5>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row mb-2" *ngFor="let score of testRecord.scores">
        <span class="col">{{score.rightAnswer}}</span>
        <span class="col">{{score.wrongAnswer}}</span>
        <span class="col">{{score.date}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Component's code:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.subscribeToReduxStores(); 
    this.getUserTestRecords();
   }

  private subscribeToReduxStores = () => {
    const user$ = this.store.select((state) => {      
      return state.userState
    })

    user$.subscribe(user => {     
      this.testRecords = user.testRecords;
      console.log('TestRecordsComponent.testRecords', this.testRecords)
   })
 }

  private getUserTestRecords = () => {
    this.userService.getUserTestRecords();
  }
```

testRecords within the component displayed to the console.

> TestRecordsComponent.testRecords
> (7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
> 0
> :
> {topic: 'Force, Motion and Energy', subtopic: 'Conservation of Energy', scores: Array(4)}
> 1
> :
> {topic: 'Force, Motion and Energy', subtopic: 'Newtons Laws of Motion', scores: Array(1)}
> 2
> :
> {topic: 'Human Anatomy and Physiology', subtopic: 'Homeostasis', scores: Array(1)}
> 3
> :
> {topic: 'Biodiversity', subtopic: 'Interactions between Species', scores: Array(3)}
> 4
> :
> {topic: 'Genetics', subtopic: ' DNA Structure and Function', scores: Array(1)}
> 5
> :
> {topic: 'Biodiversity', subtopic: 'Classification of Species', scores: Array(1)}
> 6
> :
> {topic: 'Force, Motion and Energy', subtopic: 'Work and Machines', scores: Array(2)}
> length
> :
> 7

I think I see the problem, but I don't know why it is happening. The above data logged to the console from within the component shows that testRecords is an array containing 7 objects. However, testRecords logged to the console just before the *ngFor loop shows that testRecords is 7 seven distinct arrays as shown below.

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Comment: You need to show more code, where is the data coming from in the class?

Comment: I have added the code from the component.

Comment: are you using `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` (if true is possible you need inject the [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#usage-notes) and write `this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();` inside subscribe function)? has you any error in console?

Comment: I am using the default change detection as I am throughout the application. Only here I am having this problem. And there is no error in the console.

Comment: Can you reproduce in a StackBlitz? The code looks correct so hard to know what to suggest

Comment: @koque, Whether the `ngFor` iterates over collection if you remove `{{testRecords}}` from the beginning of the template?   
I mean highly likely the service returns `Observable`. It typically doesn't cache values.

Comment: I think I see what the problem is. Please see the addition to my original question.

Comment: I have gotten this error before but how I solved it will be slightly different given your code. Let us do some experimenting here. Try adding | date:'fullDate'  in your <span class="col">{{score.date}}</span> and tell me if console log shows the data and not object

Final code should like this  <span class="col">{{score.date | date:'fullDate'}}</span>

Comment: Got an error:  No pipe found with name 'date'.

18             <span class="col">{{score.date | date:'fullDate'}}</span>

Comment: And I removed the span with the date and still got the same problem.

Comment: Could you try to use an Observable in ngFor, like this <div class="row mb-2" *ngFor="let testRecord of (testRecords$ | async)">

This is an example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xvthdn?file=src/main.ts

Comment: Can add `Array.isArray(this.testRecords)` and `this.testRecords.length` to the log? And it would be good to reduce the for-loop body to the minimum. Maybe just `{{ testRecord | json }}<hr>`

Comment: Even though testRecords logged to the console shows an array, typeof testRecords shows an object.

Comment: @koque That's a correct behavior - even `typeof []` returns `'object'`. That's why it's better to try `Array.isArray()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I originally created TestRecords under the subjects common module so TestRecords was declared in SubjectsModule. I decided it was more appropriate under the user common module so I deleted TestRecords from subjects and copied it under user but forgot to declare it in UserModule.

I suppose Angular automatically used AppModule as the module for TestRecords. And I also suppose the ngFor directive is in CommonModule which was not imported in AppModule. The problem went away once I declared TestRecords in UserModule where CommonModule is also imported.

To the best of my understanding, this was the issue. It simply went away once I declared TestRecords in UserModule.